# GC.AddMemoryPressure() not enough to trigger the Finalizer queue execution on time

Tags: c#, c++, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection

We have written a custom indexing engine for a multimedia-matching project written in `C#`.

The indexing engine is written in unmanaged `C++` and can hold a significant amount of unmanaged memory in the form of `std::` collections and containers.

Every unmanaged index instance is wrapped by a managed object; the lifetime of the unamanaged index is controlled by the lifetime of the managed wrapper.

We have ensured (via custom, tracking C++ allocators) that every byte that is being consumed internally by the indexes is being accounted for,  and we update (10 times per second) the managed garbage collector's memory pressure value with the deltas of this value  (Positive deltas call `GC.AddMemoryPressure()`, negative deltas call `GC.RemoveMemoryPressure()`).

These indexes are thread-safe, and **can be shared by a number of C# workers, so there may be multiple references in use for the same index.  For that reason, we can not call `Dispose()` freely, and instead rely on the garbage collector to track reference sharing and eventually to trigger the finalization of the indexes once they are not in use by a worker process.**

Now, the problem is that **we are running out of memory**. Full collections are in fact executed relatively often, however, with the help of a memory profiler, we can find a very large number of "dead" index instances being held in the finalization queue at the point where the process runs out of memory after exhausting the pagination file.

We can actually circumvent the problem if we add a watchdog thread that calls  `GC::WaitForPendingFinalizers()` followed by a `GC::Collect()` on low memory conditions, however, from what we have read, calling `GC::Collect()` manually severely disrupts garbage collection efficiency, and we don't want that.

We have even added, to no avail, a pessimistic pressure factor  (tried up to 4x)  to exaggerate the amount of unmanaged memory reported to the .net side, to see if we could coax the garbage collector to empty the queue faster. It seems as if the thread that processes the queue is completely unaware of the memory pressure.

At this point we feel we need to implement a manual reference counting to `Dispose()` as soon as the count reaches zero, but this seems to be an overkill, especially because the whole purpose of the memory pressure API is precisely to account for cases like ours.

Some facts:

- .Net version is 4.5
- App is in 64-bit mode
- Garbage collector is running in concurrent server mode.
- Size of an index is ~800MB of unmanaged memory
- There can be up to 12 "alive" indexes at any point in time.
- Server has 64GB of RAM

**Any ideas or suggestions are welcome**

Comment: My understanding is that manually calling `GC::Collect()` throws off it's self-tuning behavior, but in this case, I don't think it matters. I think this is a perfectly okay situation to not trust the framework's self-tuning.

Comment: Seems like whenever something calls `Dispose` on your managed wrapper, you need to free native mem.  Whatever you do, you absolutely positively need a way to deterministically cleanup the large mem.  Are you using the Dispose Pattern correctly?

Comment: @ChrisO, the wrapper is written on C++/CLI, and we are using the destructor (~) and finalizer(!) operators as recommended by Microsoft. According to the documentation, the Dispose pattern is automatically implemented correctly when both operators are implemented as suggested. We can ascertain that the memory is released deterministically if we dispose the wrapper, the problem is that we can't call `Dispose()` freely because the instance is frequently shared among threads, and controlling the point where we can dispose safely would require a reference count mechanism.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the explanation, I get it now.  I think your idea of the reference count mechanism is the best bet.  That way, you can ensure that mem is released as soon as the reference goes to zero.  But like @CollinDauphinee suggests, you can call `GC::Collect()` when you like and as often as you like, which becomes necessary when dealing with objects of larger memory.

Comment: Did you try to check if there any memory leaks? You can use this too to check: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42933

Comment: @Matt, yes, we can confirm that we have no memory leaks. If we keep the watchdog thread running that monitors the available memory and waits for the pending finalizers and calls GC::Collect when available memory is low, the server can run uninterruptedly.  This seems to solve the problem, but we are surely messing with the garbage collector's statistic auto-tuning.  :(

Comment: @CollinDauphinee  -  the drawback we see in leaving the ´GC::Collect()´ call is that the managed side holds a very large number of long-lived objects.  We fear that by calling GC:Collect() we might be forcing the garbage collector to sweep the references more than necessary.

Comment: So, have you tried aggressively calling `GC::Collect()` then?  Use a profiler to help determine if doing that is actually detrimental or not, but please don't guess.

Comment: Not sure, if applicable to you, but it might help: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/the-dangers-of-the-large-object-heap/

Comment: Are you sure your finalizers actually work? They shouldn't take much time to execute either. Maybe some of your finalizers are blocking others or something - there's not much we can tell you with just such generic information.

Comment: @Luaan,  yes they do work, but the garbage collector seems to process the finalizer queue with very low frequency and it seems as if the frequency is not altered by the fact that the memory pressure is very high.

Comment: Have you tried analyzing a dump in WinDbg (SOS)? Are the objects unrooted in a finalizable queue, or are they in the freachable queue? How long does the finalize call take? How often do you get a Gen 2 collection? Try putting marks before the allocation, during it and after it should be unreachable, compare the reference trees - do they look correct? When a collection comes around, does the object get into the freachable queue? What is the finalizer thread doing?

Comment: @Luaan - no I haven't used WinDbg, just a commercial memory profiler that shows a relatively large number of index instances in the finalization queue (there's no differentiation as far as I cant teel between finalizable and freachable queues, I guess the product is either merging them or just reporting one of them).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, there will be no answer but "if you want to dispose external resource explicitly you had to do it by yourself".

`AddMemoryPressure()` method does not guarantee to trigger garbage collection immediately. Instead, CLR uses unmanaged memory allocation/deallocation stats to adjust it's own gc thresholds and GC is triggered only if it is considered appropriate.

Note that `RemoveMemoryPressure()` does not trigger GC at all (theoretically it *can* do it due to side effects from actions such as setting GCX_PREEMP but let's skip it for brevity). Instead it decreases the current mempressure value, nothing more (simplifying again).

Actual algorithm is undocumented, however you may look at the implementation [from CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/bc146608854d1db9cdbcc0b08029a87754e12b49/src/vm/comutilnative.cpp#L1989). In short, your `bytesAllocated` value had to exceed some dynamically calculated limit and then the CLR triggers the GC.

Now the bad news:

- In the real app the process is totally unpredictable as each GC collection and each third-party code have an influence on the GC limits. The GC may be called, may be called later on may not be called at all
- GC tunes it limits trying to minimize the costly GC2 collections (you're interested in these as you're working with long-lived index objects add they're always promoted to the next generation due to finalizer). So, DDOSing the runtime with huge mem pressure values may strike back as you'll raise the bar high enough to make (almost) no chance to trigger the GC by setting the mem pressure at all.
  (**NB:** the last issue will be fixed with [new AddMemoryPressure() implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/bc146608854d1db9cdbcc0b08029a87754e12b49/src/vm/comutilnative.cpp#L2089) but not today, definitely).

**UPD:** more details.

Ok, lets move on : )

***Part 2, or "newer underestimate what _udocumented_ means"***

As I've said above, you are interested in GC 2 collections as you are using long-lived objects.

It's well-known fact that the finalizer runs almost immediately after the object was GC-ed (assuming that the finalizer queue is not filled with other objects).
As a proof: just run [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ig-sinicyn/1488857d22c2d07c753d).

The *real* reason why your indexes are not freed is pretty obvious: the generation the objects belongs to is not GCed. 
And now we're returning to the original question. How do you think, how much memory you had to allocate to trigger the GC2 collection?

As I've said above actual numbers are undocumented. In theory, GC2 may not be called at all until you consume very large chunks of memory.
And now really bad news comes: for server GC "in theory" and "what really happens" are the same.

[One more gist](https://gist.github.com/ig-sinicyn/95a3dacdd56289dfb978), on .Net4.6 x64 the output will be alike this:

```
GC low latency:
Allocated, MB:   512.19          GC gen 0|1|2, MB:   194.19 |   317.81 |     0.00        GC count 0-1-2: 1-0-0
Allocated, MB: 1,024.38          GC gen 0|1|2, MB:   421.19 |   399.56 |   203.25        GC count 0-1-2: 2-1-0
Allocated, MB: 1,536.56          GC gen 0|1|2, MB:   446.44 |   901.44 |   188.13        GC count 0-1-2: 3-1-0
Allocated, MB: 2,048.75          GC gen 0|1|2, MB:   258.56 | 1,569.75 |   219.69        GC count 0-1-2: 4-1-0
Allocated, MB: 2,560.94          GC gen 0|1|2, MB:   623.00 | 1,657.56 |   279.44        GC count 0-1-2: 4-1-0
Allocated, MB: 3,073.13          GC gen 0|1|2, MB:   563.63 | 2,273.50 |   234.88        GC count 0-1-2: 5-1-0
Allocated, MB: 3,585.31          GC gen 0|1|2, MB:   309.19 |   723.75 | 2,551.06        GC count 0-1-2: 6-2-1
Allocated, MB: 4,097.50          GC gen 0|1|2, MB:   686.69 |   728.00 | 2,681.31        GC count 0-1-2: 6-2-1
Allocated, MB: 4,609.69          GC gen 0|1|2, MB:   593.63 | 1,465.44 | 2,548.94        GC count 0-1-2: 7-2-1
Allocated, MB: 5,121.88          GC gen 0|1|2, MB:   293.19 | 2,229.38 | 2,597.44        GC count 0-1-2: 8-2-1
```

That's right, in worst cases you had to allocate ~3.5 gig to trigger the GC2 collection. I'm pretty sure that your allocations are much smaller:)

**NB:** Note that dealing with objects from GC1 generation does not make it any better. The size of GC0 segment may exceed 500mb. You had to try really hard to trigger the garbage collection on the ServerGC :)

**Summary:** the approach with Add/RemoveMemoryPressure will have (almost) no influence on the garbage collection frequency, at least on server GC.

Now, the last part of the question: what possible solutions do we have?
In short, the simplest possible approach is to do ref-counting via disposable wrappers.

***To be continued***

Comment: thanks for your response.  In fact we can tell that the 'AddMemoryPressure()' call indeed makes the garbage collector run more aggressively, as we measured the number of full collections performed with and without the calls.  Our gripe is with the finalizer queue.  It is letting a very large number of "dead" objects linger for too much time. It seems to be unaware that the memory level is critical.   Indeed we feel we will fallback on ref-counting. I'll just see if more answers or suggestions appear for a while; otherwise you're getting the accepted answer.

Comment: let me see if I understood you right.  The triggering of the garbage collection may be made based on a threshold that in practice may have little relationship with the amount of available memory?

Comment: @BlueStrat exactly. As far as I can remember the only thing related to available memory is a low memory notification from the OS. Here's [a proof](https://books.google.ru/books?id=fhpYTbos8OkC&pg=PA136&dq=clr+gc+triggers&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAWoVChMI3ffOy5-KyQIVwVRyCh2tcg8_#v=onepage&q=clr%20gc%20triggers&f=false)

Answer (score 3):

> we can find a very large number of "dead" index instances being held in the finalization queue

It does not make any sense that these "dead" instances are not getting finalized.  After all, you found out that GC::WaitForPendingFinalizers() actually works.  So what must be going on here is that they are actually finalized, they are just waiting for the *next* collection to run so they can get destroyed.  And that is taking a while.  Yes, that is not unlikely, after all you already called GC::RemoveMemoryPressure() for them.  And, hopefully, released the big unmanaged allocation for them.

So this is surely just a false signal, these objects only take up GC heap, not unmanaged heap and GC heap is not your problem.

> We have ensured (via custom, tracking C++ allocators) that every byte...

I don't much like the sound of that.  Pretty important that the GC calls have *some* correspondence to actually creating and finalizing managed objects.  Very simple to do, you call AddMemoryPressure in your constructor and RemoveMemoryPressure in your finalizer, right after you called the C++ `delete` operator.  The value you pass only needs to be an estimate for the corresponding C++ unmanaged allocation, it doesn't have to be accurate down to the byte, being off by a factor of 2 is not a grave problem.  It also doesn't matter that the C++ allocation happens later.

> calling GC::Collect() manually severely disrupts garbage collection efficiency

Don't panic.  Pretty high odds that, since your unmanaged allocations are so large, that you rarely collect "naturally" and actually need forced allocations.  Like the kind that GC::AddMemoryPressure() triggers, it is just as "forced" as calling GC::Collect().  Albeit that it has a heuristic that avoids collecting too frequently, one you might not particularly care about right now :)

> Garbage collector is running in concurrent server mode

Don't, use workstation GC, it is much more conservative about heap segment size.

Comment: The part about "they are actually finalized" is wrong:) The finalizer thread does not stop (however it's paused on GC as all another threads with managed code). If user code does not block finalizer thread all finalizers are called almost immediately after GC.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I said.

Comment: Hello @HansPassant, I think I get your point.  So, in the bottom line, your suggestion would be that we call GC::WaitForPendingFinalizers()- where the finalizers should run and free the unmanaged memory - without calling GC::Collect() immedately next, right?

Comment: I never suggested that, no idea where you got that from.  Your post is too vague to give a specific "push this button to solve all your problems" advice, I can only respond to what you told us.

Comment: Sorry @HansPassant, I'm a bit confused - the big unmanaged allocation is released on the finalizer, so I don't get the point where I hopefully  released the unmanaged allocation. That would require the finalizer to run, and from my understanding the safe way to force it would be by calling GC::WaitForPendinfFinalizers() (that's where I got the ide)  - sorry If I gave the impression of a "push this button" solution, I don't.  I just want to frame your answer into my limited understanding.

Comment: @HansPassant - I think I understood now your first point, what you are explaining to me is that even if the memory profiler finds objects in the finalization queue, it doesn't necessarily mean that the finalizer has not been executed for those instances - they will still linger there until the next collection, with no unmanaged memory held at this point, right?

Comment: Yes, quite right.  You'll always find a bunch of them.

Answer (score 2):

I want to suggest a brief read about "[Finalizers are not guaranteed to run](http://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/)". You can test it easily by continuously generating good old `Bitmap`s by yourself:

```
private void genButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() => GenerateNewBitmap());
}

private void GenerateNewBitmap()
{
    //Changing size also changes collection behavior
    //If this is a small bitmap then collection happens
    var size = picBox.Size;
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);
    //Generate some pixels and Invoke it onto UI if you wish
    picBox.Invoke((Action)(() => { picBox.Image = bmp; }));
    //Call again for an infinite loop
    Task.Run(() => GenerateNewBitmap());
}
```

It seems on my machine that if I generate more than 500K pixels, I can't generate forever and .NET gives me an `OutOfMemoryException`.
This thing about `Bitmap` class was true on 2005 and it is still true in 2015. `Bitmap` class is important because it exists in the library for a long time. Having bug fixes, performance improvements along the way, what I think is *if it can't do something I need, then I need to change my need*.

First, the thing about a disposable object is you need to call `Dispose` by yourself. No, you really need to call it yourself. **Seriously**. I suggest enabling relevant rules on VisualStudio's code analyze and making use of `using` etc. appropriately.

Second, calling a `Dispose` method does not mean calling `delete` (or `free`) on the unmanaged side. What I did, and I think you should, is to use **reference counting**. If your unmanaged side makes use of C++ then I suggest using [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). Since VS2012, as far as I know, VisualStudio supports `shared_ptr`.

Therefore, with reference counting, calling a `Dispose` on your managed object decreases the reference count on your unmanaged object and the unmanaged memory gets deleted only if that reference counts gets down to zero.

Comment: Nice idea, I hadn't realized that the Dispose pattern could be used to decrease the reference count.  Better than try-finally. Thanks!

Comment: shared_ptr is available in Visual Studio 2008 (assuming service pack(s) have been applied), though it is available in the std::tr1 namespace, not std.